# AngularJS and Google SEO Indexing

Tags: angularjs, indexing, seo

I am not a specialist in SEO, and some time talking to one told me that Google indexes, which is in the **view-source**, I wonder if this is really true?

I am developing an application and took Angle and quite advanced, and I remembered and I wonder if this is true or not.

Why? I ask this.
Because my code in the **view-source** looks like this

```
<article class="uk-article" ng-controller="dataItemHoP">
   <h1 class="uk-article-title"><span>Información</span></h1>
   <h3 class="uk-article-lead"><span>{{nombreHoP}}</span></h3>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Dirección:</span> <br>
      <span>{{direccion}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{ciudad}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{estado}}</span></p>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Teléfonos:</span> <br>
   <span>{{telefono1}}</span><span>,</span> <span>{{telefono2}}</span></p>
</article>
```

**While on the console looks like Google**

```
<article class="uk-article ng-scope" ng-controller="dataItemHoP">
   <h1 class="uk-article-title"><span>Información</span></h1>
   <h3 class="uk-article-lead"><span class="ng-binding">Lidodotel Hotel Boutique</span></h3>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Dirección:</span> <br>
   <span class="ng-binding">Centro Comercial Sambil, autopista Antonio Jose de Sucre, sector Las Lomas, edificio Lidotel</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">San Cristóbal</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">Táchira</span></p>
   <p><span class="uk-text-bold">Teléfonos:</span> <br>
   <span class="ng-binding">0276 5103333</span><span>,</span> <span class="ng-binding">0276 5103334</span></p>
</article>
```

¿So, Google doesn't will Indexed because into the view-source is watching the {{ expression }} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google indexer is getting much better at handling JavaScript heavy sites that deal with a lot of AJAX actions to bring in content. It is true that the indexer used to only really deal in the textual representation of your site. However that has been updated.

See [Understanding Web Pages](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html?m=1)

> In order to solve this problem, we decided to try to understand pages by executing JavaScript. It’s hard to do that at the scale of the current web, but we decided that it’s worth it. We have been gradually improving how we do this for some time. In the past few months, our indexing system has been rendering a substantial number of web pages more like an average user’s browser with JavaScript turned on.
>
> Sometimes things don't go perfectly during rendering, which may negatively impact search results for your site. Here are a few potential issues, and – where possible, – how you can help prevent them from occurring:

As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884690/angularjs-and-google-seo-indexing/39884882#comment67056646_39884882) pointed out, you should also see [Deprecating Our Ajax Crawling Scheme](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html?m=1)

> Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers. To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files.

Comment: also note that the linked reference is several years old meaning more improvements. This official link very relevant also from a year ago https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: Oh Thanks! i see the post on the webmasters blog.

Answer (score 1):

Although Gbot can read javascript for a very long time, it is still not very reliable on Production scale.

As a webmaster myself we are still using the "pre-render" method